# Jquery can't find content of div which itself show that div

Tags: jquery, contains, show

I show hidden div via `$('#something').show()` but when

I search in content via jQuery, jQuery can't find my search, but jQuery can find already displayed div!

Why?

In the beginning class `full_text`'s display equal none, then when I click on the index tags the browser should scroll to finded text in all page:

```html
<ul class="panel">
    <li onclick="return goToTag('tag1');">tag1</li>
    <li onclick="return goToTag('tag2');">tag2</li>
    <li onclick="return goToTag('tag3');">tag3</li>
</ul>

<!--page content-->
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="short_text">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="full_text" style="display:none">
        ...
    </div>
<div>

<!--goToTag function works on other contents! but it doesn't work on on full_text class-->

<script>
function goToTag(text) {
            $('.full_text').parents('.panel').removeClass("less");
            $('.full_text').parents('.panel').addClass("open")
            $('.expandable_new').children('i').removeClass('fa-sort-desc').addClass('fa-sort-asc');
           
            $('.short_text').hide();
            $('.full_text').show(1, function() {
                console.log(text);
                if ($("#main-content *:contains('" + text + "'):last").length > 0) {
                    $(window).scrollTop($("#main-content *:contains('" + text + "'):last").offset().top);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

But jQuery can find in this page other divs which displayed before:

Comment: We need to see more relevant code.

Comment: Please see [ask], then put some HTML along with your script in a demo using the editor.

Comment: I inserted my codes

Comment: Just a heads up, the `return` keyword in your `onclick` functions is unnecessary.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can even make it a runnable reproduction using a Stack Snippet (use the `<>` button)